# Can a company track your browsing history if you are not connected to the company network?

Tags: privacy, user-tracking, safe-browsing-filter

I am using the Internet from my laptop at home, and am not connected to my company's network.  I am using my own Vodafone dongle for my Internet connection. I was logged in to Gmail using my work e-mail address and forgot to sign out, and so I want to know if browsing the Internet while logged into this account could have allowed my company to track what I was browsing at that time.

Comment: Does anyone at your company have your GMail work email password?  If so then they can check our Google browsing history tied to that account at any time.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't disabled search history, they'd be able to look at your searches if they go to the search history record for your account.  You can check your own Google search history by logging in [here](https://accounts.google.com/Login?continue=https://history.google.com/history/&hl=en).

They may also be able to track activity on other Google services, like Youtube, Maps, News, etc since they've implemented Single Sign-On which logs you in to all of their services together.  But if the laptop and internet connection are not controlled by your company, it is unlikely that they'd be able to get anything not related to Google.